# Postfix: mails sent through sendmail binary are blocked because of wrong HELO

Tags: postfix, sendmail, hostname

My server is using Centos 6.5
I updated from Plesk 11.5 to 12 last week and postfix to 2.8.17.
Since then, all mails sent using the sendmail binary (notifications, mail forwards...) are being rejected with a wrong HELO hostname: localhost.
It seems that sendmail is using locahost as a HELO tag which is not accepted.

Thank you in advance for your help

Here is the following error:

```
Jun 23 14:23:20 ns395167 plesk sendmail[29817]: handlers_stderr: SKIP
Jun 23 14:23:20 ns395167 plesk sendmail[29817]: SKIP during call 'check-quota' handler
Jun 23 14:23:20 ns395167 postfix/pickup[29480]: B94BC6AA20A6: uid=0 from=<root@curuba.fr>
Jun 23 14:23:20 ns395167 postfix/cleanup[29507]: B94BC6AA20A6: message-id=<20140623122320.B94BC6AA20A6@ns395167.ip-176-31-117.eu>
Jun 23 14:23:20 ns395167 greylisting filter[29824]: Starting greylisting filter...
Jun 23 14:23:20 ns395167 greylisting filter[29824]: Wrong HELO hostname: localhost
Jun 23 14:23:20 ns395167 /usr/lib64/plesk-9.0/psa-pc-remote[29457]: handlers_stderr: REJECT
Jun 23 14:23:20 ns395167 /usr/lib64/plesk-9.0/psa-pc-remote[29457]: REJECT during call 'grey' handler
Jun 23 14:23:20 ns395167 /usr/lib64/plesk-9.0/psa-pc-remote[29457]: Message aborted.
Jun 23 14:23:20 ns395167 postfix/cleanup[29507]: B94BC6AA20A6: milter-reject: DATA from localhost[127.0.0.1]: 5.7.1 Command rejected; from=<root@curuba.fr> to=<root@curuba.fr>
Jun 23 14:23:20 ns395167 postfix/cleanup[29507]: B94BC6AA20A6: to=<root@localhost.localdomain>, orig_to=<root@curuba.fr>, relay=none, delay=0.12, delays=0.12/0/0/0, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (Command rejected)
Jun 23 14:23:20 ns395167 postfix/cleanup[29502]: C594B6AA20A8: message-id=<20140623122320.C594B6AA20A8@ns395167.ip-176-31-117.eu>
Jun 23 14:23:20 ns395167 postfix/bounce[29506]: B94BC6AA20A6: sender non-delivery notification: C594B6AA20A8
Jun 23 14:23:20 ns395167 postfix/qmgr[29481]: C594B6AA20A8: from=<>, size=2211, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 23 14:23:20 ns395167 postfix/cleanup[29502]: CFFE56AA2094: message-id=<20140623122320.C594B6AA20A8@ns395167.ip-176-31-117.eu>
Jun 23 14:23:20 ns395167 postfix/local[29721]: C594B6AA20A8: to=<root@localhost.localdomain>, orig_to=<root@curuba.fr>, relay=local, delay=0.08, delays=0.04/0/0/0.04, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (forwarded as CFFE56AA2094)
Jun 23 14:23:20 ns395167 postfix/qmgr[29481]: CFFE56AA2094: from=<>, size=2361, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 23 14:23:20 ns395167 postfix/qmgr[29481]: C594B6AA20A8: removed
Jun 23 14:23:20 ns395167 postfix-local[29825]: postfix-local: from=MAILER-DAEMON, to=admin@curuba.fr, dirname=/var/qmail/mailnames
Jun 23 14:23:20 ns395167 postfix-local[29825]: Unable to get sender domain by sender mailname
Jun 23 14:23:20 ns395167 dk_check[29826]: DK_STAT_NOSIG: No signature available in message
Jun 23 14:23:20 ns395167 postfix-local[29825]: handlers_stderr: PASS
Jun 23 14:23:20 ns395167 postfix-local[29825]: PASS during call 'dd52-domainkeys' handler
Jun 23 14:23:20 ns395167 postfix/pipe[29508]: CFFE56AA2094: to=<admin@curuba.fr>, orig_to=<root@curuba.fr>, relay=plesk_virtual, delay=0.1, delays=0.04/0/0/0.06, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via plesk_virtual service)
Jun 23 14:23:20 ns395167 postfix/qmgr[29481]: CFFE56AA2094: removed
```

Here is my postconf -n content:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
disable_vrfy_command = yes
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
message_size_limit = 10240000
mydestination = localhost.$mydomain, localhost, localhost.localdomain
myhostname = ns395167.ip-176-31-117.eu
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128 176.31.117.106/32 [2001:41d0:8:3c6a::1]/128, 50.57.69.12/32
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
non_smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:12768 unix:/var/spool/postfix/ctmilter/ctmilter.sock
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.8.17/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.8.17/samples
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/sdd_transport_maps
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_send_xforward_command = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_use_tls = no
smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_rbl_client xbl.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client b.barracudacentral.org
smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:12768 unix:/var/spool/postfix/ctmilter/ctmilter.sock
smtpd_proxy_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/blacklists, permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/postfix_default.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = $smtpd_tls_cert_file
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_use_tls = yes
transport_maps = , hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/transport
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = $virtual_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual
virtual_gid_maps = static:31
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/qmail/mailnames
virtual_mailbox_domains = $virtual_mailbox_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual_domains
virtual_mailbox_limit = 0
virtual_mailbox_maps = , hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/vmailbox
virtual_transport = plesk_virtual
virtual_uid_maps = static:30
```

My system hostname seems correct:
    hostname -f
    ns395167.ip-176-31-117.eu
    hostname
    ns395167.ip-176-31-117.eu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those action are expected behavior of postfix. Here the snippet from [this page](http://www.postfix.org/MILTER_README.html#non-smtp-milters) from official documentation.

> There's one small complication when using Milter applications for non-SMTP mail: there is no SMTP session. To keep Milter applications happy, **the Postfix cleanup(8) server actually has to simulate the SMTP client** CONNECT and DISCONNECT events, and the SMTP client EHLO, MAIL FROM, RCPT TO and DATA commands.
>
> When new mail arrives via the sendmail(1) command line, the Postfix cleanup(8) server pretends that **the mail arrives with ESMTP from "localhost" with IP address "127.0.0.1"**. The result is very similar to what happens with command line submissions in Sendmail version 8.12 and later, although Sendmail uses a different mechanism to achieve this result.

Looking in the logs and output of `postconf -n`, its clear that the process who reject it was milter application running via inet:127.0.0.1:12768. It's `psa-pc-remote` milter provided by Plesk.

While I don't have any experience with Plesk, some workaround is turn off that milter for **non_smtpd** only. Well, I don't know this is bad or good advice because I don't know what `psa-pc-remote` do to your email. Another way, you can look some setting in Plesk to turn off this kind of rejection.

Comment: I better understand why all my attempts to adjust postfix config failed. Now I will post a request on Plesk forum and at the same time try to investigate your two advises.

Comment: I have commented the line in main.cf and now mails sent from sendmail are working fine again. I don't know what will be the side effects, but anyway not having sendmail functionality when hosting sites is not acceptable.
I have posted a question on Plesk forum here http://goo.gl/7CH5l1
Thank you again for your quick and efficient reply. I highly appreciate your expertise and your help.

Comment: In the future, if you get better answer from Plesk forum, please (1) edit my answer for alternative solution or (2) you can post that with your own answer.

Comment: Sure I will. For now, Plesk team is not providing any satisfying answer.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was a solution to comment out the following line in /etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
non_smtpd_milters
```

Comment: masegaloeh answer has *explicitly* said the same solution as yours :) ---> `While I don't have any experience with Plesk, some workaround is turn off that milter for non_smtpd only. `

Answer (score -4):

Try setting `milter_protocol=2` in `postfix/main.cf`.