# Postfix/OpenDKIM not signing PHP sent emails

Tags: php, postfix, centos6, zend-framework, opendkim

We installed SPF, DKIM, and DMARC records for email security/verifiability.

When sending through the console or a mail client like Outlook or Mac's Mail it processes fully and has all three pass.

When sending through Zend Framework 1.12's SendMail function it fails (php).

Did we miss a configuration at some point to have php emails signed as well? What file do we look into? Or does there have to be a different installation/add-on?

We are using OpenDKIM and Postfix, on Cent OS 6

**postfix -n result:**

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain, mail.$mydomain, www.$mydomain, ftp.$mydomain
mydomain = example.com
myhostname = server1.example.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/32
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
non_smtpd_milters = 
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,  permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/pki/tls/certs/mail.example.com.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/pki/tls/private/mail.example.com.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_transport = dovecot
```

This is the results I get from Port25 email checker. All is the same except DKIM is missing when zend.

**Non-Zend Regular Headers:** *DKIM Signed*

```
Return-Path: <darius@example.com>
Received: from server1.example.com (123.123.123.123 (my server ip)) by verifier.port25.com id hrh7ri20i3gm for <check-auth@verifier.port25.com>; Thu, 12 Feb 2015 02:01:13 -0500 (envelope-from <darius@example.com>)
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com; spf=pass smtp.mailfrom=darius@example.com
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com; domainkeys=neutral (message not signed) header.From=darius@example.com
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com; dkim=pass (matches From: darius@example.com) header.d=example.com
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com; sender-id=pass header.From=darius@example.com
Received: from [111.111.1.111] (cpe-11-11-111-111.socal.res.rr.com [76.94.200.240])
    by server1.example.com (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id 33F233800A9
    for <check-auth@verifier.port25.com.>; Wed, 11 Feb 2015 23:01:11 -0800 (PST)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=example.com;
    s=default; t=1423724471;
    bh=qMnrIAg7afoneBTtI0hU9OrDkqChYZOD1f4AUvZtdGw=;
    h=From:Subject:Date:To;
    b=g4lXm/vQ54wq/B0fCAf/U3Hj3hi2N2jojst+5lURCfykwhvzjqCm/Z5VGz3rcu
    MoZCfxEkCI4OyQqW2kch93h93h93j3kbuCg3Pehl2WlgoLJy2S8CMR68ygNU52+P88
    IG/vq2YShK6ctLUxRq4O79IYzKcInRiXuWOtuV3A=
From: Darius <darius@example.com>
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Subject: Give me a test result. Thank you.
Message-Id: <68D428E0-84CD-46EC-B326-2FC15BE565AE@example.com>
Date: Wed, 11 Feb 2015 23:01:00 -0800
To: check-auth@verifier.port25.com.
Mime-Version: 1.0 (Mac OS X Mail 8.2 \(2070.6\))
X-Mailer: Apple Mail (2.2070.6)
```

**And this is the Zend Version of Headers Results:** ***NOT*** DKIM Signed

```
Return-Path: <apache@example.com>
Received: from server1.example.com (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (my server ip)) by verifier.port25.com id hr9du620i3gl for <check-auth-darius=example.com@verifier.port25.com>; Tue, 10 Feb 2015 14:28:35 -0500 (envelope-from <apache@example.com>)
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com; spf=pass smtp.mailfrom=apache@example.com
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com; domainkeys=neutral (message not signed) header.From=noreply@example.com
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com; dkim=neutral (message not signed)
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com; sender-id=pass header.From=noreply@example.com
Received: by server1.example.com (Postfix, from userid 500)
    id 08E073800AA; Tue, 10 Feb 2015 11:28:25 -0800 (PST)
To: check-auth-darius=example.com@verifier.port25.com
Subject: mydomain Test
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 5004:Sendmail.php
From: mydomain Test <noreply@example.com>
Date: Tue, 10 Feb 2015 11:28:24 -0800
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
boundary="=_af78e87ff18206603cb724d073777150"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Message-Id: <20150210192825.08E073800AA@server1.example.com>
```

Comment: Just for note, the OP said this the original question (before edited): *I apologize I reposted this after deleting the [previous](http://serverfault.com/questions/666567/opendkim-dkim-not-included-in-php-zend-framework-sent-emails-centos-6?noredirect=1#comment814744_666567) (I posted my full name and IP address in other one by accident, and freaked).*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When sending through the console or a mail client like Outlook or Mac's Mail it processes fully and has all three pass.

This behavior was expected because you place this configuration in `main.cf`

```
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
```

> When sending through Zend Framework 1.12's SendMail function it fails (php).

This behavior was expected too because you place this configuration in `main.cf`

```
non_smtpd_milters =
```

#### Explanation

By default, OpenDKIM was combined with postfix through [milter](http://www.postfix.org/MILTER_README.html). Enabling/Disabling milter application was controlled by [`smtpd_milters`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_milters) and [`non_smtpd_milters`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#non_smtpd_milters) parameters. For application who send email through smtpd, the correspondence parameter is `smtpd_milters`, for sendmail, the parameter is `non_smtpd_milters`

#### Solution

Replace `non_smtpd_milters =` with

```
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
```

Comment: Works perfectly now! Thank you! Is there anything I should be concerned about by setting non_smtpd_milters to that? Dangers, etc.?

Comment: Yes, for example this [Plesk case](http://serverfault.com/a/607284/218590)